# Rails - User Populate/Change ZIP code location using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm developing an ecommerce application which requires user to enter his/her zip code location to show the listing closer to his/her area. I have a popup window and making an api call to ziptasticapi.com I'm able to get city, state and country for a given zip code. Code is below:

```
 $('#locationModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('#zipcode-name').keyup(function (e) {
      var zipCode = $("#locationModal").find("input[name='zip']").val();
      if (zipCode.length===5 && $.isNumeric(zipCode)){
        var requestURL = 'http://ziptasticapi.com/' + zipCode + '?callback=?';

        $.getJSON(requestURL, null, function(data){
          console.log(data);
          if (data.city) $("#locationModal").find("input[name='city']").val(data.city);
          if (data.state) $("#locationModal").find("input[name='state']").val(data.state);

        });
      }
  });
});
```

I'm populating city and state in my popup window but I'm having problem to show the city and state in my navbar front page. What I'm looking for exactly is:
1. When the user visit the ecommerce website automatically a popup window shows up and ask for the zipcode.
2. Show user city and state in my navbar with option to change location.
3. Use the zipcode provide by the user to search the item list and show items closer to the user.

How can I do that? Please I need some help here. 
Thanks in advance.

I am using Spree ecommerce and I created another model called listing besides products model. On my listing model I have zipcode as database column to be able to search by zipcode on this model.

For some reason I thought to better have another model that I called Zip to have zipcode, city, state, country to store them in database and associate this Zip model to Listing.  I'm thinking to have zip belongs_to listing.

That is the frontend code I have so far:

```
      <nav class="col-md-12">
         <div id="location-nav-bar" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <%= link_to 'change location', '#', {'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#locationModal'}  %>
```

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="locationModal" tabindex="-1"    role="dialog" aria-labelledby="locationModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
             </button>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="form-control-label">ZIP Code:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zip", id="zipcode-name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city", id="city-name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="state", id="state-name">
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="summitcode", id="zipcode-summit">Summit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  (function($){

$('#locationModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('#zipcode-name').keyup(function (e) {
      var zipCode = $("#locationModal").find("input[name='zip']").val();
      //window.alert(zipCode);
      if (zipCode.length===5 && $.isNumeric(zipCode)){
        //window.alert(zipCode);
        //console.log(zipCode);
        var requestURL = 'http://ziptasticapi.com/' + zipCode + '?callback=?';

        $.getJSON(requestURL, null, function(data){
          console.log(data);
          if (data.city)  $("#locationModal").find("input[name='city']").val(data.city);
          if (data.state) $("#locationModal").find("input[name='state']").val(data.state);

         }); 
    }

  });
})

})(jQuery);

</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a minimum example of your code? It's hard to gauge what you want out of the answers from your question.

Comment: I added some code.